# Clickhouse on Kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, clickhouse

When trying to deploy Clickhouse operator on Kubernetes, by default access_management is commented out in users.xml file. Is there a way to uncomment it when installing kubernetes operator?

Clickhouse Operator deployment:

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-operator/raw/0.18.3/deploy/operator/clickhouse-operator-install-bundle.yaml
```

I have tried to do that through "ClickHouseInstallation" but that didn't work.

Furthermore, Clickhouse operator source code doesn't contain parameter for access_management

Comment: Please add the command you're using to deploy clickhouse operator.

Comment: You can set any parameters when you create CHI. see https://github.com/Altinity/clickhouse-operator/blob/master/tests/e2e/manifests/chi/test-011-secured-cluster-2.yaml#L32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look to `kubectl explain chi.spec.configuration.files` and `kubectl explain chi.spec.configuration.users`

try

```yaml
apiVersion: clickhouse.altinity.com/v1
kind: ClickHouseInstallation
metadata:
  name: access-management-example
spec:
  configuration:
    files:
      users.d/access_management.xml: | 
         <clickhouse><users>
           <default><access_management>1</access_management></default>
         </users></clickhouse>
```

you shall carry on itself about replicate RBAC objects during change cluster layout (scale-up)